# how to apply one jTable double click mouse event to different jFrames in same package

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I have a jTable in a jFrame named "StudentSearching Form". What i wanted to do is if the user not remember the Student_Id , go to Student Searching form and search by name , then u get the Student_Id which belongs to filtered name and set it into a jTextField in the Frame called "StudentRegistration form" .I have done those stuff pretty good so far. But the problem I over came is according to my code I only can set Student_Id to the Frame called "StudentRegistration form". I have few different Frames like "StudentAttendance Form","Student Payment Form","StudentExams Form" that should get Student_Id by searching same "StudentSearching Form" above mentioned.

So please help me on this..... 
Thank you.

Here is my code :

```
private void jTable1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
int rw =jTable1.getSelectedRow();
String k = jTable1.getValueAt(rw, 0).toString();

if(evt.getClickCount()==2){

SMStudentRegistrationForm sms= new SMStudentRegistrationForm();


this.dispose();
sms.setVisible(true);
sms.jTextField1.setText(k);


}


}
```

there is a link(jButton) to go to "StudentSearching Form" in every above mentioned Frame and get Student_ID on required Frame. Can Only get Student_Id on SMStudentRegistrationForm Frame . 
If(StudentExams Form jButton pressed){
I Should be able to enter the Student_Id to "StudentExams Form" jTextField
} 
This will help to solve the problem I suppose. But Dont know how to do it , using java codes.
Im using netbeans IDE ..

Comment: listener on where ????

Comment: listener on where ???? what I have done this far is working well. But I need to improve it as above mentioned. Get Student_Id on required Frame. Can only get on SMStudentRegistrationForm Frame using above mentioned code. if I would be able to put a "If statement" which can choose from where I came  to this "StudentSearching Form" Frame (clicking which jButton linked to "StudentSearching Form" situated in above mentioned frames Ex: IF I came by clicking jButton of the "Student Payment Form" Frame then I should get the Student_Id on that Frame.) that would be more helpful.

Comment: For better help, you should post an SSCCE http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define own listener e.g. `ChangeSelectedStudentListener` with just one method

```
void studentIdChanged(int newId);
```

Let all your dependent forms implement the listener. On change they should update their internal state (change text field values, retrieve some id dependent data from DB etc).

In your search form define `addChangeSelectedStudentListener()` method which stores all the aded listeners in a list. All your dependent forms should call the addChangeSelectedStudentListener(this) to let their listeners be registered. On double click on the table iterate through the listeners list and for each item call `studentIdChanged(clickedStudentId)`

Thus all your forms are notified about student change and could update their states.

Comment: By this all the forms are  changing I suppose. But I just needed to change only the required form. Once I get Student_Id from search form(by double clicking),it should change only the required form which I want to get Student_Id on its own TextField.